# Mysql stored procedure returns blob as null

Tags: mysql, null, blob, procedure

I'm trying to get blob record (image) from mysql database to vba userform pictureimage.

Mysql table "images" has structure = id int, image1 blobmedium.
If I use

```
SELECT id, image1 FROM images
```

I got this :

[select statement returns id and also blob column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABPWv.png)

I wrote mysql stored procedure GetImageNow to get this blob (image) from database:

```
DELIMITER // 

CREATE PROCEDURE GetImageNow()
BEGIN
SELECT id, image1 FROM images;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this procedure, it returns null in image1 column. I dont understand why

[stored procedure returns null in blobmedium column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bal0.jpg)

Comment: Test does `SELECT id, image1, LENGTH(image1) len1 FROM images` returns NULL in the second option really.
`

Comment: I tried this sql command, result len1 = 2504. It means there are the data, but I cannot read it.

Comment: This is your printing software problem... from the other side this is logical - BLOB is binary data whereas you try to print it as HTML which is textual.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thanks for advice. Finally I got the code to read image from database and load it to Picturebox on userform:

```
Private Sub ReadImageFromDB ()

    Dim cnSqlConn As New ADODB.Connection
    cnSqlConn.Connectionstring = "DSN=XXX"
    cnSqlConn.Open
    

    /* create command for running mysql stored procedure GetImage */

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnSqlConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "GetImage"
        .CommandTimeout = 15
    End With
    

    /* read blob image from database via ADODB.Stream and save it temporarily on disk*/
    
    Dim rsImage as New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rsImage = cmd.Execute

    Dim stm As New ADODB.Stream
    With stm
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write rsImage.Fields("image1").Value 
        .SaveToFile "d:\Temp.jpg", adSaveCreateOverWrite
    End With

    /* load the picture into Image on userform */
    Userform1.imgImageFromDatabase.Picture = LoadPicture("d:\temp.jpg")
    Kill ("d:\temp.jpg")
 
    rsImage.Close
    Set rsImage = Nothing
    cnSqlConn.Close
    Set cnSqlConn = Nothing
    Set stm = Nothing

End Sub
```